# The orbits with respect to two groups from the same conjugacy class are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, polya-counting-theory

On the Wikipedia page for the Symbolic Method of Flajolet and Sedgewick

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_method_(combinatorics)

under the heading "Classes of combinatorial structures" it states: "The orbits with respect to two groups from the same conjugacy class are isomorphic."

Does anyone know of a proof of this? Perhaps something like:

Definitions/notation:

- $G$ is a group.
- $X$ is a set.
- $\psi: G \times X \rightarrow X$ is a $G$ action on $X$.
- $H$ and $H^{\prime}$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$ — that is,
  $H^{\prime} = gHg^{-1}$ for some $g \in G$.
- $H$ and $H^{\prime}$ act on $X$ by the restrictions of $\psi$ to $H$
  and $H^{\prime}$, respectively.
- $\text{orb}_{H}(x)$ and $\text{orb}_{H^{\prime}}(x)$ denote the
  orbits of $x \in X$ with respect to $H$ and $H^{\prime}$,
  respectively.
- $\phi$ denotes the isomorphism between $H$ and $H^{\prime}$ defined
  by $\phi(h) = ghg^{-1}$.

Now, define the function $f: \text{orb}_H(x) \rightarrow \text{orb}_{H^{\prime}}(\psi(g, x))$ by
\begin{equation*}
f(\psi(h, x)) = \psi(\phi(h), \psi(g, x)).
\end{equation*} Then, $f$ is a well-defined bijection and
\begin{align*}
f(\psi(h, z)) = \psi(\phi(h), f(z)).
\end{align*}
Many thanks.

Comment: What's the definition of "isomorphic orbits"?

Comment: I assume in the sense of G sets. That is, that there exists a bijection between the orbits which is compatible with the group actions.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, particularly after getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After defining conjugacy as a group action, it follows from the definition that the orbits  are now the conjugacy classes.